# Invalid cookies recieved from CURL request and file_get_contents

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers, file-get-contents

I am receiving an invalid cookie string when trying capture the cookie using `file_get_contents` and `curl`. The cookie received while browsing directly from the browser is valid/active. But, the cookie captured from `file_get_contents` and `curl` seems to be invalid.

I am trying to capture from `file_get_contents` like this

```
 $context =      array(
  'http' => array(
   'method' => 'GET',
   'header' => array('Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*\/*;q=0.8', 'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/63.0.3239.84 Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36'),
  )
 );

   $cxContext = stream_context_create($context);


    file_get_contents($url, false, $cxContext);
    $cookies = array();

    foreach ($http_response_header as $hdr) {
    if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]+)/', $hdr, $matches)) {
        $cookies = $matches[1];
    }

}
return $cookies;
```

I tried playing around with this, by setting headers, but the cookies returned always is either expired or simply invalid.

But, through a browser the cookie I get is always valid.

Anyone faced a similar problem, don't know how to tackle this issue.

Comment: You mention curl, but you're not using curl in your code that you've presented.  There's also no indication of any kind of cookie jar in use (to store the cookie so you can resend it to the server so the server doesn't keep generating a new one for you each time). You also mention that the cookies returned are either "expired or invalid" - which is it? Are they sometimes valid but expired, or sometimes not expired but invalid? What does "invalid" mean here?

Comment: @jhilgeman The cookie just cannot pass authentication as required. The cookies stored in the cookie jar using curl, cannot pass authentication. But, if I copy/paste the cookie - the one saved in browser, it passes the authentication. Fiding hard to put it in words, but curl / file_get_contents request is somehow being filtered and the sent cookie string seems to be invalid

Comment: What kind of authentication are you referring to? There's no authentication measures shown in your example code.

Comment: Oh, wait - you're saying that "invalid" cookies are cookie values that are rejected by the server. Perhaps the problem isn't the cookie storage but how the original cookie is requested. If you're trying to emulate the browser, you'll need to follow its steps accurately (e.g. hit a login page, then POST the login form data, etc...).

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that more and more sites are using bits of Javascript as part of their authentication scheme so that browsers will interpret the JS and update form data correctly while script-based approaches like this will miss out on the JS and post invalid data. It's hard to say for sure without seeing a full example.

Comment: The host where I want to connect, issues an ASP.NET SessioID cookie while making a GET request into their server. This same cookie is used for subsequent requests. I am doing the same with CURL capturing the cookie from the first GET request, and using the same cookie for subsequent requests, but this fails on the final stage. I am not sure why :( The final stage is for phone code verification when the correct verification code is entered it return unsuccessful. Now, if I set the cookie to be the same as the browser, it returns successful.

Comment: You are correct, sending an ajax request actually succeeds. But, two problems arise - `cross site` blocking and `mixed content` as my website is served over https but the server I am trying to communicate with is in http

Comment: Use fiddler to capture traces of both browser and script activity and compare them. There's probably a difference you're missing. Possibly a different http header or something.

Comment: Is fiddler a tool or an extension? I am using Linux, is there a tool for linux too?

Comment: It's a tool - just Google for fiddler for Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several unanswered questions from my above comment, but I'll share this bit of code for example purposes. It's what I've used in the past as a base class for browser emulation using cURL:

```
<?php
if(!function_exists("curl_init")) { throw new Exception("CurlBrowser requires the cURL extension, which is not enabled!"); }
class CurlBrowser
{
    public $userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0";
    /*
    Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0
    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1");
    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0 
    */

    public $cookiesFile = null;
    public $proxyURL = null;
    public $saveLastOutput = "";
    public $caBundle = "cacert.pem";
    public $httpHeaders = array();

    public function __construct($UseCookies = true)
    {
        if(is_bool($UseCookies) && $UseCookies)
        {
            $this->cookiesFile = dirname(__FILE__)."/cookies.txt";
        }
        elseif(is_string($UseCookies) && ($UseCookies != ""))
        {
            $this->cookiesFile = $UseCookies;
        }
    }

    public function SetCustomHTTPHeaders($arrHeaders)
    {
        $this->httpHeaders = $arrHeaders;
    }

    public function SetProxy($proxy)
    {
        $this->proxyURL = $proxy;
    }

    public function Get($url)
    {
        return $this->_request($url);
    }

    public function Post($url,$data = array())
    {
        return $this->_request($url,$data);
    }

    private function _request($form_url,$data = null)
    {
        $ch = curl_init($form_url);

        // CA bundle
        $caBundle = $this->caBundle;
        if(file_exists($caBundle))
        {
            // Detect and convert relative path to absolute path
            if(basename($caBundle) == $caBundle)
            {
                $caBundle = getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  . $caBundle;
            }
            // Set CA bundle
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $caBundle);
        }

        // Cookies
        if($this->cookiesFile !== null)
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookiesFile);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookiesFile);
        }

        // User Agent
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->userAgent); 

        // Misc
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip, deflate");

        // Optional proxy
        if($this->proxyURL !== null)
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxyURL);
        }

        // Custom HTTP headers
        if(count($this->httpHeaders))
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->httpHeaders);
        }

        // POST data
        if($data !== null)
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        }

        // Run operation
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if($result === false)
        {
          throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
        }
        else
        {
            if(!empty($this->saveLastOutput))
            {
            file_put_contents($this->saveLastOutput,$result);
          }
          return $result;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

You'd use it like so:

```
<?php
$browser = new CurlBrowser();
$html = $browser->Get("https://....");
...etc...
```

My gut guess is that you're simply missing a cookie jar in your original code, but that's mostly based on gut feeling, since we don't have all your problem code at this time.